# Android/Java Store names from a text file in String array, and integers in int array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, inputstream

I'm working on java code in android studio and I'm trying to take names from a text file and store them in  a string array, and integers (test scores) and store them in an integer array.  I can't change the text file due to restrictions placed by my teacher.  The text file is in the assets folder.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this, I've searched and can find similar questions, but nothing that seems to apply to my situation.  Thanks!

The text file contents are:

```
Name            Test1   Test2   Test3   Final
Adam    Anderson    81  90  85  87
Ben Brown       77  80  68  94
Chris   Cross       74  80  56  62
Don Dare        86  94  90  89
Eric    Earl        96  93  90  98
Fred    Foley       79  92  59  86
Gina    Gray        80  83  95  87
Holly   Hank        74  77  75  78
Ian Ingram      66  64  56  60
Jill    Johnson     90  98  78  89
```

My current code up to this point is:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class App1Act1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app1_act1);
        int[] testScores;
        String[] studentNames;


        //error message
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        AssetManager am = getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream inputT = am.open("grades.txt");

            for(i=0; i<11; i++){
                studentNames[i] = //???
            }

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            dlgAlert.setMessage("File was not found, please import file and try again.");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Oops!  Something happened!"); //in the tradition of windows 10
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
        }

        finally {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_app1_act1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do with the data after you've read it from the file? Storing test scores of diffent tests from multiple students in a one-dimensional array (`int[] testScores`) makes it difficult to retrieve the score e.g. by student name.

Comment: Are you forced to store this data in separate arrays? Otherwise I'd look at making a model class that contains fields for each of the headings, and each row is a record (i.e. a class called `Student` which contains a name field, and some score fields. Makes retrieving data a lot easier because it's grouped together logically.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic, after I get the data stored, I'm going to (ideally) store each name in a spinner and then depending on the name selected in the spinner get the average of that student's test score.  I don't have to store the data in separate arrays, that was just the route I was taking at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

- Make sure you open the file correctly.
- Avoid any processing on the first line, thus is just a header line.
- Use [string tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to split the lines by spaces. So you now the first string in a call to hasMoreTokens() will be the First Name, the second call 'll be the Last Name, and the next call give you the numeric values.
- Use Integer.parseInt() method to convert the string into int.

Of course this is just an approach, i am sure you could do something much better than my recommendation.